# Get some indentification of client

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

This may seem a silly question, but I'm kind of trouble in a problem here.

I need to collect some information from the browser to help me identify the customer who is browsing.
I already know the MAC address I will not get. But it would be possible to get a handle of the browser installed? Maybe some installation ID, or something to help me identify the customer who is using my application?

Thank you.

Comment: The simple answer is 'no'. The more complex answer is that MAC address is easily faked and should not be used for any security task. Can you just have a user log in to your app and set a cookie or JWT token? In what context do you need to know the customer, and for how long? Keep in mind a single customer can change browsers or computers.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike, I Know the customer can change. My idea is monitoring the computer and not the user. 
I'm building an anti-fraud logic for a system of reviews. Where a single person can change user reviews and make fakes using the same computer. Understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Detect Browser</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    "Name is " + navigator.appName +
    "<br>Code name is " + navigator.appCodeName;
}
</script>
```

There are lots of ways to do browser detection, do a little bit of research via google on browser detection, there is lots of information, also there are good posts on stackoverflow that show ways to do it. Like 
[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: I need to get identification of my client via browser. Some unique identification. The basic properties of browser I already got.

Comment: If you need more identifying information, you could try by IP, the answer in this link shows how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I found what I was looking for.
I will use a technique based on [FingerPrint](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/is-browser-fingerprinting-a-viable-technique-for-identifying-anonymous-users) with a [plugin](http://valve.github.io/blog/2013/07/14/anonymous-browser-fingerprinting/) called fingerprintjs

Based from N variables contained in the browser you can generate a hash as a unique identifier for that machine.

I'll use too, the  [Evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie) techinique to store information.

Thanks a lot.